# Updating multiple windows at once

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In my WPF application, I receive UDP data at 100 ms interval. I have to display the data in multiple windows. The UDP server runs on a separate thread and calls the main UI thread through Dispatcher.Invoke for UI updates. Since there is only one main UI thread, the updates to the different windows is not parallel i.e., first UI in one window is updated, then another window.

Is there a way to divide the UI thread so that all the windows are updated simultaneously?

Comment: No there isn't.  There is one UI thread and any thread can only do one thing at a time.  That said, an actual UI update should be quite quick.  It's quite possible that you're actually doing more on the UI thread than just updating the UI.  Make sure you do all non-UI-specific work first and then do nothing but update the UI on the UI thread.  Unless you a lot of things to update on the UI, it should look pretty close to simultaneous.

Comment: if I write only code related to updating UI in Dispatcher.Invoke, then I wont be able to access any UI elements to set other properties/ check conditions etc because I will get error saying that the object I am trying to access belongs to a different thread.

Comment: The answer to your original question is "no".  That's all there is to that.  If you want what you do on the UI thread to be done as quickly as possible then you have to do as little as possible on the UI thread.  If you have a lot to do then it will take time and that's that.  If you'd like some advice on optimising what you're doing then we'd need some information on what you're actually doing.  It's quite possible that you can break it up into more than one step and do some on the secondary thread and some on the UI thread but it's pure speculation if we don't know what you're doing now.

Comment: What all are you doing as part a of "updating the UI" on the UI thread, can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create and run your windows in new UI threads

```
var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart( () =>
{        
    var window= new Window();
    window.Show();

    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
}));

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);   
thread.IsBackground = true;   
thread.Start();
```